# When is the fixed point set of an element from a topological group closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space on which $G$ acts continuously. Let $Fix(g) := \{ x \in X: g \cdot x = x \}$ for $g \in G$. I'm wondering when is $Fix(g)$ guaranteed to be closed for any $g$?

I know that if $X$ is first countable, then this is guaranteed: picking a point outside $Fix(g)$, we can find a countable nested neighborhood basis around it, and if we assume no neighborhood of the point stays outside $Fix(g)$, we obtain a sequence of fixed points of $g$ converging to our point, and by uniqueness of limits and continuity of the action we obtain that the point is actually in $Fix(g)$.

Without a countable nested neighborhood basis, I can't see how to do it. Is it still true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always closed. Here's a simple argument: define $F_g:X  \to X \times X$ by $F_g(x) = (g\cdot x,x)$. Then $F_g$ is continuous because the map $X \ni x \mapsto g\cdot x\in X$ is continuous. Next, let $\Delta = \{(x,y)\in X \times X \mid x=y\}$ be the diagonal of $X$. We have that $\Delta$ is closed in $X \times X$ because $X$ is Hausdorff (in fact, they're equivalent). Finally, ${\rm Fix}(g) = F_g^{-1}[\Delta]$ is closed in $X$ because it is the continuous inverse image of something closed.